# Compact Implies Closed

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

In general, i believe, it is not true that Compact Implies Closed. At least it is true that Compact does not imply closed and bounded. However, in case of differentiable manifolds, since they are homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^n$ I was wondering if Compact Implies closed.

Is it true?

Comment: Compact implies closed for any Hausdorff space.

Comment: I guess you meant to ask about the reverse implication -- does closed and bounded imply compact (on a differentiable manifold).

Answer (score 2):

The usual definition of compactness of $X$ assumes $X$ is $T_2$ or hausdorff. In case you do assume that, then each compact subset $C$ of a Hausdorff Space $Y$ is closed. To show this assume that $y\in Y\backslash C$. For each $c\in C$ you will find open neighbourhoods $U_c$ of $c$ and $V_c$ of $y$ which are disjoint, since $Y$ is hausdorff. A finite number of $U_c$ will cover $C$, the intersection of the corresponding $V_c$ is an open neighbourhood of $y$ which is disjoint from $C$. Hence $C$ is closed.

Note that this proof remains correct if $Y=C$.